# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors() JUnit5 - Java17 - IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit5, java-17

I'm migrating a project from Java 11 to 17 at the same time move from Junit4 to Junit5. I modify all test, and add this dependencies

```
 <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
             <version>5.9.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
             <version>5.9.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

but when I try to run a test, it executes the body of the method bu at the end throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.getTestClassNames(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:50)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

I know that there is similar questions but all of them works with build, I'm using maven 3.9.6. I've already check the  dependecy tree I can't share it here but here is the part of the test dependencies

```
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.1:compile
```

thanks for your advise

I want to figure out how to syncronize the junit versions in compile and runtime, since I think the problem is because they are different, but I don't find the difference

Comment: First I recommend to use the bom to define the dependencies for JUnit Jupiter (https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/ see also https://youtube.com/@khmarbaise also please show the full pom file? Do you use most recent version of the plugins like maven-surefire-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ...

Comment: well, I can't share the full pom. And I'm using version 3.2.2 in maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: The tree shows that you have junit-platform-laucher version 1.10.1 which is related to JUnit Jupiter 5.10.1 and NOT 5.9.1 ... That means you are using a dependency which also has a dependency to JUnit Jupiter... As I already mentioned use the BOM to define the parts for JUnit Jupiter ...also the question what kind of project is that? Spring Boot? Or another kind?

Comment: well, It's a legacy project, right now I'm using springframework. and thanks. I'm fixing the versions with the bom.

Comment: yeap, the problem was the versions between Junit Jupiter and the platform launcher.  Thank you. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for the dependencies in JUnit Jupiter you should use the BOM approach:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.2</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      ..
    ..
  ..
```

That should be defined before all other parts in your dependencyManagement...